# How do you pass data between 2 ViewControllers without displaying a Viewcontroller, seguing, or changing the frame

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
protocol useForDist {
   func findpindist()
}

class ViewController1: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, useForDist {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func findpindist() {
        print("Test")
    }
}

class HomePageController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: useForDist?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate?.findpindist()
    }
}
```

Why is this not printing Test? Am I missing an aspect? I do not want a segue to a different view controller or a pop-up of one or a displaying. I'm  new to XCode/Swift so if this is easily solvable bear with me :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright I have a couple of suggestions for you!! First off, I would change your function to have public on the front of it. So it would look something like this:

```
    public func findpindist() {
        print("Test")
    }
```

Put is outside of your viewcontroller class and you should be able to call it in homePageViewController by putting `findpindist()` in the viewDidLoad.

However, this looks sloppy and is very buggy so I have a better solution for you! There is something called NotificationCenter. This will allow you to pass data between viewcontrollers without a segue or anything.  To use this, first put this code inside the viewDidLoad of the homePageController

```
   NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("findpindist"), object: nil, userInfo: ["message":"Test"])
```

Next, add this code to your viewController1. the observer stays in the viewDidLoad and the objective c function goes outside of the viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(findpindist(_:)), name: Notification.Name("findpindist"), object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func findpindist(_ notification: Notification){
        let message = notification.userInfo!["message"] as! String
        print(message)
    }
```

As long as you have your viewController1 loaded, it should print the statement. you can use this code to send any data between viewControllers. This should help with what I think you are trying to achieve, but as the other person said, I'm not sure what your objective is.

heres some additional resources:
[Posting Messages with NotificationCenter](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-post-messages-using-notificationcenter)
[A deep walkthrough of NotificationCenter](https://medium.com/@nimjea/notificationcenter-in-swift-104b31f59772)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a few things.

first, you need to access to second ViewController `ViewController`  from the first ViewController `HomeViewController`.

Second, you need to set the `HomeViewController` delegate.

```
import UIKit

protocol useForDist: AnyObject {
   func findpindist()
}

class HomePageController: UIViewController {
    
    weak var delegate: useForDist?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // First
        let VC = ViewController()
        
        // Second
        delegate = VC
        
        delegate?.findpindist()
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, useForDist {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func findpindist() {
        print("Test")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked